# Pandas groupby.diff() not returning expected output

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, difference

I have an outer group and an inner group and I wish to find the difference within each inner group depending on the outer group. Normally, I can nest the inner group within each outer group using `groupby` but, for some reason, the `diff` function for `groupby` returns a flat vector instead of a nested array.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'inner':list('aabbccddee'),'outer':[0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0],
    'value':np.random.randint(0,100,10)})

    inner  outer  value
0     a      0     78
1     a      0     68
2     b      1     78
3     b      1     22
4     c      0     53
5     c      0     25
6     d      1     82
7     d      1     38
8     e      0      2
9     e      0     39
```

If I desire the `sum`, for example, for the inner group for each outer group, I simply use `groupby`:

```
In [19]: df.groupby(['outer','inner']).sum()
Out[19]:
             value
outer inner
0     a        146
      c         78
      e         41
1     b        100
      d        120
```

The above is the correct output and it works for all other functions *except* `diff`. When I use `diff`, I want output in a format similar to the above but instead, I get:

```
In [20]: df.groupby(['outer','inner']).diff()
Out[20]:
   value
0    NaN
1  -10.0
2    NaN
3  -56.0
4    NaN
5  -28.0
6    NaN
7  -44.0
8    NaN
9   37.0
```

The above is equivalent to `df.groupby(['inner']).value.diff()` so it seems `groupby` is not considering the outer group. I can find workouts for this no problem but using `groupby` for this would be more elegant and succinct. Does anyone know why this is happening and how it could be remedied?

Comment: Diff will go via each value in your each group , which mean if you have 3 value , you will have 2 diff

Comment: @W-B currently, `groupby` isn't even considering the outer group. The output you see is the exact same as if I were to do `df.groupby(['inner']).value.diff()` so I am not sure how your comment addresses the question. In fact, it doesn't matter how many outer groups there are, the output is always the same.

Comment: You second group level even do not need , since each group level 1 only have one unique level 2, so that df.groupby(['inner'])=df.groupby(['outer','inner']), only the index is different

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Functions like  `s.diff()`, `cumsum` etc are non aggregation function hence you would get the result in shape of a series, you could use [`np.diff()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.diff.html) here, example below:

```
print(df.groupby(['outer','inner'])['value'].apply(lambda x: np.diff(x).item()))

outer  inner
0      a       -10
       c       -28
       e        37
1      b       -56
       d       -44
```

Comment: This works as desired, thank you! I had no idea that there are functional differences in these functions.

Comment: @GeneBurinsky Thank you for the accept . Glad I could help you. :)